# How fill the fields user and Password on web page

Tags: java, android, web, submit, user-input

Hello  (sorry for my english)

On a Android mobile I know reach a web page (java android), but on this page there are 2 fields and a button :

> Login [             ]
>   Pwd   [             ]
>        [submit button]

Could you please say me if it is possible to fill this two fields and activated the submit button automaticaly from a soft JAVA android ?

I don't know if it is possible.
If not, I don't want lost time.
If Yes, what is the principle (no detail), or a good Hyperlink to do that.

Tanks

Domi

Answer (score 0):

It can't. Because its a webview. You just load the url. If you want to fill it. You've to modify that html page.